# want to check an element of array is present in first line of a file

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, grep, array

```
while read line ;
 do
 if grep -q "${MYARRAY[$i]}" <<< "$line";
 then
  echo its present
  else
  echo its not
 fi
 i+=1
  done < keyans.txt
```

here `keyans.txt` has all answers and `MYARRAY` is an array that contains users answers,I want to compare if first element of array is present in first line of `keyans.txt` file and second is present in second so on and if present display yes else display no

Comment: If you make `i` an integer variable before the loop (`declare -i i`) or change `i+=1` to `(( i += 1))` or `i=$((i+1))`, your current code might work. `i+=1` appends the string `1` to the variable `i` by default, unless `i` has the integer attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In such scenarios you almost never need to count. By interchanging the `while` and `for` loops we can do as follows which you can modify as per needs.

```
for el in "${MYARRAY[@]}"
do
  if IFS= read -r line < keyans.txt
  then
    case $line in
      *"$el"*) echo Present ;;
            *) echo Not present
    esac
  else
    break
  fi
done
```